# Get model position from objects ( Position is not exact)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello guys,

i never get an answer to my problem so i think i will describe the problem a bit better this time.

So i want to get the position of the Objects in my world. It worked good so far the problem is that the x value is 0.5 above or below the correct position. System is Linux 16.04. Ros Kinetic. Gezabo 7.0

Here is my code:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, name, relative_entity_name):
        self._name = name
        self._relative_entity_name = relative_entity_name
class Tutorial:
    _blockListDict = {
    'a': Block('cardboard_box', 'link'),
        'b': Block('bookshelf_0', 'link'),
        'c': Block('cabinet', 'link'),
        'd': Block('mars_rover', 'link'),
        'e': Block('Dumpster_0', 'link'),
    'f': Block('unit_box_0', 'link'),
        'g': Block('fire_hydrant', 'link'),
    'h': Block('first_2015_trash_can', 'link'),
    

    }
    def update_gazebo_modelPoints(self):
        try:
            i = 0
            plist = []
            model_coordinates = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state',GetModelState)
            for block in self._blockListDict.itervalues():
                blockName = str(block._name)
                resp_coordinates = model_coordinates(blockName,block._relative_entity_name)
                plist.append(Point(resp_coordinates.pose.position.x,resp_coordinates.pose.position.y,0))
            return plist
        except rospy.ServiceException as e:
            rospy.loginfo("Get Model State service call failed:  {0}".format(e))
```

So my first object stands on Point(5,5,0)

Here is the screenshot from simulation:
[image: image description]

If i run the code i got this:
[image: image description]

Its the same with all objects .

Hope u can help me !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20885/get-model-position-from-objects-(-position-is-not-exact)/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just a guess (cause i don't know the sdf files of your models), but it seems that you are asking for the model_states in a specific frame

```
   `resp_coordinates = model_coordinates(blockName,block._relative_entity_name)`
```

each model position will be relative to `block._relative_entity_name`. I assume that the service will just take the 'link' frame of the models. and there might be the static offset.

You should instead call the service like this:

```
   `resp_coordinates = model_coordinates(blockName,"")`
```

the empty relative frame will cause that the position is in global "world" or "map" frame.

---

Originally posted by [wentz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2629/wentz/) with karma: 350 on 2018-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3848/baumboon/) on 2018-11-04**:
thank u for ur help. It worked fine !